# Harp Server, Jade and JSON Loop, Error: Cannot read property "length" of undefined

Tags: json, pug, harp

This is the nav.jade file

```
each link in data
h5.home-link: a(href="#{ url }")
```

This is my data.json file

```
{
      "links": [
        { "url": "index.html", "pg-title": "Home" },
        { "url": "Wooden_Wall_Panelling.html", "pg-title": "Wooden Wall Panelling" },
        { "url": "Wooden_Partitioning.html", "pg-title": "Wooden Partitioning" },
        { "url": "Wardrobe_MDF_Shutters.html", "pg-title": "Wardrobe MDF Shutters" },
        { "url": "MDF_Ceiling_Patterns.html", "pg-title": "MDF Ceiling Patterns" },
        { "url": "Wooden_Grills.html", "pg-title": "Wooden Grills" }
     ]
}
```

Error(while Jade tries to compile the file):

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

The error is pointed on the first line i.e each link in data.

What am I doing wrong here?

I am using Harp Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure it’s a `_data.json` file, with an underscore in front. Then, your `nav.jade` file should look like this:

```
each link in public._data.links
  h5.home-link: a(href="#{ link.url }") #{ link["pg-title"] }
```

If you change your `pg-title` to `title` in your `_data.json` file, you can also make the syntax a little cleaner:

```
each link in public._data.links
  h5.home-link: a(href="#{ link.url }") #{ link.title }
```

You can also drop the string interpolation if you want:

```
each link in public._data.links
  h5.home-link: a(href=link.url)= link.title
```

There’s also more about info about [metadata in Harp here](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/metadata). If you’re debugging and want to see how all your metadata is available in Harp, you can be helpful to temporarily display the entire public `_data` object:

```
pre: code= JSON.stringify(public._data, 0, 2)
```